# Importing packages in Java

Tags: java, import, package

How to import a method from a package into another program? I don't know how to import... I write a lil' code:

```
package Dan;
public class Vik
{
    public void disp()
    {
        System.out.println("Heyya!");
    }
}
```

and then, saved it in a folder named "Dan" and I compiled it. The .class file is generated. Then, I wrote this code below:

```
import Dan.Vik.disp;
class Kab
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Vik Sam = new Vik();
        Sam.disp();
    }
}
```

and I saved it outside the folder "Dan" and it says : "cannot find symbol"

I saved the first code in C:\Dan\Vik.java
and the second in C:\Kab.java

Comment: If you use an IDE, it will add the `import` statements for you automatically.

Comment: `import Dan.Vik` you import the class not the method.

Comment: Try `import Dan.Vik;` instead.

Comment: Why are you minusing the guy? Well he is a trully beginner, but the question is valid.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't import methods in Java, only types:

```
import Dan.Vik;
class Kab
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Vik Sam = new Vik();
        Sam.disp();
    }
}
```

The exception is so-called "static imports", which let you import class (`static`) methods from other types.

Answer (score 12):

In Java you can only import *non-primitive types*, or *static* methods/fields.

To import types use `import full.package.name.of.TypeName;`

```
//example
import java.util.List; //to import List interface
```

to import static methods/fields use

```
import static full.package.name.of.TypeName.staticMethod;
import static full.package.name.of.TypeName.staticField;

//example
import static java.lang.Math.max; //to import max method(s)
import static java.lang.Math.PI; //to import PI field
```

Answer (score 8):

Take out the method name from in your import statement. e.g.

```
import Dan.Vik.disp;
```

becomes:

```
import Dan.Vik;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
import Dan.Vik;
```

This makes the class visible and the its public methods available.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the right way to do imports in Java.

```
import Dan.Vik;
class Kab
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Vik Sam = new Vik();
    Sam.disp();
}
}
```

You don't import methods in java. There is an advanced usage of static imports but basically you just import packages and classes.
If the function you are importing is a static function you can do a static import, but I don't think you are looking for static imports here.

Comment: No no no no, Apurv, that's not the way to format your code in Java.

Comment: What's the hysteria "No no no no" about?

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can only import class Names, or static methods/fields.

To import class use

```
import full.package.name.of.SomeClass;
```

We can also import static methods/fields in Java and this is how to import

```
import static full.package.nameOfClass.staticMethod;
import static full.package.nameOfClass.staticField;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second class file, add "package Dan;" like the first one, so as to make sure they are in the same package; modify "import Dan.Vik.disp;" to be "import Dan.Vik;"