# Java quickSort Vectors

Tags: java, vector, quicksort

I'm trying to convert a function that i had that quickSorted an array into a vector quicksort function.
I keep getting this cannot find symbol. This is my function that im trying to adapt into vector quickSort

```
public static void quickSort(Vector<Personne> arr, int low, int high, Personne[] pers) {
    if (arr.isEmpty() == true || arr.size()== 0)
        return;

    if (low >= high)
        return;

    int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
    int pivot = arr.get(middle).getNumero();
    int i = low, j = high;

    while (i <= j) {
        while (arr.get(i).getNumero() < pivot) {
            i++;
        }

        while (arr.get(j).getNumero() > pivot) {
            j--;
        }

        if (i <= j) {
            Vector<Personne> temp = new Vector<Personne>();
            temp.add(arr.get(i));
            arr.get(i).add(arr.get(j));

            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    if (low < j)
        quickSort(arr, low, j, pers);

    if (high > i)
        quickSort(arr, i, high, pers);
}
```

This part of the function is giving me errors:

```
if (i <= j) {
    Vector<Personne> temp = new Vector<Personne>();
    temp.add(arr.get(i));
    arr.get(i).add(arr.get(j));
    i++;
    j--;
}
```

I tried `.get()` ,`.elementAt()` ,creating a new temp vectors that will hold the information but I just can't seem to fix it.

**error**

> C:\Users\Arnold\Desktop\numero3.java:241: error: cannot find symbol
>   arr.get(i).add(arr.get(j)); ^ symbol: method add(Personne) location:
>   class Personne 1 error

Comment: what is error you get?

Comment: and that if clause, do you exchange anything? I think not

Comment: give me a symbol error

Comment: Not with that tone... Paste your stacktrace.

Comment: im sorry if i offended anyone. But what is a stacktrace?

Comment: It's a joke, I guess you meant *"[It keeps] giv[ing] me a symbol error."* Anyways, paste the error that gets spit from the console out when you try to compile. ***[What is a Stacktrace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)***.

Comment: i believe it is this? C:\Users\Arnold\Desktop\numero3.java:241: error: cannot find symbol
    arr.get(i).add(arr.get(j));
              ^
  symbol:   method add(Personne)
  location: class Personne
1 error

Comment: If `Personne` is in another package or directory, you need to import it. Throw in this line at the top; after your package (if applicable) `import {path.to}.Personne;`... Of course, the placeholder "`{path.to}`" is the package where that class exists. See: ***[Importing packages in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248906/importing-packages-in-java)***

Comment: your issue is **not reproducible** so I think It can be flagged as **off topic** question

Comment: personne is a class that i created to read a .txt file and convert each line into the object array

Comment: thx. i fixed it. i replaced it with Personne o=arr.elementAt(i);
    arr.setElementAt(arr.elementAt(j),i);
    arr.setElementAt(o,j);
    i++;
    j--;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error: cannot find symbol [...] symbol: method add(Personne) location: class Personne

This error is telling you that your `Personne` class does not have an `add(Personne)` method. This does not seem to be an import issue, as has been suggested in comments, because it seems you're using `Personne` objects elsewhere in your code without problem.

So, the issue is either that you don't have an `add(Personne)` method on your `Personne` class at all, in which case (seemingly questionable design practice aside) you need to add one. Or, and this is my guess, you *do* have an `add(Personne)` method on that class but it's either private (so other classes cannot *find that symbol*), or it's package-private (i.e. it has no access modifier) and you're attempting to access it from a class in another package, in which case, again, that class cannot *find that symbol*

Comment: thx. i fixed it by replacing it with Personne o=arr.elementAt(i);
    arr.setElementAt(arr.elementAt(j),i);
    arr.setElementAt(o,j);
    i++;
    j--;

Answer (score 0):

Base on this snippet code from [Program: Implement quick sort in java.](http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/quick-sort/)

```
private void exchangeNumbers(int i, int j) {
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
```

you are exchanging element in i index with element in j index , so it seems you forget to put value of `temp` to `j` index of `arr`vector

```
if (i <= j) {
    Vector<Personne> temp = new Vector<Personne>();
    temp.add(arr.get(i));
    arr.get(i).add(arr.get(j));
    arr.add(temp.get(j)); <--------forget this line
    i++;
    j--;
}
```

Note: Your `Personne` class does not have add method

> When a Java program is being compiled the compiler creates a list of
>   all the identifiers in use. If it can't find what an identifier refers
>   to (e.g., there is no declaration statement for a variable) it cannot
>   complete the compilation. This is what the cannot find symbol error
>   message is saying, it doesn't have enough information to piece
>   together what the Java code wants to execute.

Comment: oh sorry but i removed that line by accident. let me put it back. but even with that input it still keeps giving me error: cannot find symbol